# How to get the order of the sorted records' indices in Infragistics xamDataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

If we click on a field in the `XamDataGrid` UI control, the records are sorted by that field, I want the order of the records' indices after sorting.

Let `grid1` be an instance of `XamDataGrid` bidden to a datasource. After sorting by a field when I execute the following code

```cs
foreach (Record record in grid1.Records)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(record.Index);
}
```

Debug Output:

0
1
2
3
.
.
.

Which is not the sorted order. I tried `record.VisibleIndex` as well but it also gives the same result.
***Is there a way to get the indices' order of the records which the user is currently seeing?***

Comment: Check the following post: [Record Numbering (xamDataGrid)](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/xamdatagrid-record-numbering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieving by using the [`DataRecord.DataItemIndex`](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/infragisticswpf.datapresenter%7Einfragistics.windows.datapresenter.datarecord%7Edataitemindex) property. It returns the associated index in the underlying data source:

```cs
foreach (DataRecord record in grid1.FieldLayouts.DataPresenter.Records)
{                       
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(record.DataItemIndex);                
}
```

Take to account, that the record numbering in the `XamDataGrid` is starting from `1`, but index is starting from `0`.